# how to test private functions defined inside the main function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

The main question is how to test private functions defined inside the main function? Is there any way to test function in the structure (testing the functions defined inside the main function)?

**Main.js:**

```
function main (var1) {
  var a;
  //some variables
  configure(getConfig());
  function getConfig() {
    var config = {//some object...
    };
    return config;
  }

  function configure(config) {
     //do somethings;
  }
  function getSyncRates() {
    return syncrates;
  }

  this.getSyncRates = getSyncRates;//public  not waht we want

}

module.exports=(var1)=>{return new main(var1)};
```

**test.js**

```
var main=require("../js/main");
var x=main(var1).getConfig();

describe("main",function(){
  describe("getconfig",function(){
    it("getconfig return config",function(){
      assert.equal(x,config);
    });
  });
});
```

This results in:

> result (...).getConfig is not a function

Comment: ...don't? That's why they're only defined inside that function, they're apparently considered implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

This is a module design topic. A module has public and private functions. Now, by definition, the consumer of this module will only know about the public ones. **This is why you only want to have test cases that calls the public function.**

Private functions are usually abstraction of an operation that helps in increasing cohesion of a module. In simpler words, they are implementation details that may or may not change and usually don't alter the public API of the module (which is the public function interface).

*Wait what? so am I supposed to leave those lines uncovered?*

No, of course not. You should test private functions **through public functions**. So you would not have a test case where you call a private function directly. You would have tests for your public functions, passing arguments that will make the code execution to go through those private functions.

This way, your tests reflects the way other components will consume your module. They would also make for good practical documentation of the module.

```
// test.js
var createMain = require("../js/main");

describe('main module', function() {
  describe('getSyncRates()', function() {
    it('returns the sync rates', function() {
      // Arrange
      const myFirstInput = 'foo';

      // Act
      const main = createMain(myFirstInput);
      const rates = main.getSyncRates()

      // Assert
      assert.equals(30, rates);  // assuming we were expecting for the rates to be 30, when we pass 'foo' as the input
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much and the last question if you don't mind

Comment: is there any way to test javascript without using moulding design

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean with moulding design, but a test is just a piece of code where you define the inputs (arrange), call a function passing the inputs (act) and then verify the output comes as expected (assert), you can read more here: [AAA](http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrangeActAssert).  A test is agnostic to most things, including what bundling or grouping you use.